# how to properly call jquery select2 api function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have this code:

```
<div class="row add_row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Add Department*</label>

                <div class="col-sm-8 department_input_fields_wrap">
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <select class="form-control department_id" name="department_id" required>
                            <option value="">--Select department--</option>
                            <?php
                                foreach($departments as $dep) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$dep->id.'">'.$dep->department.'</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 add_job_title">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Add Job Title</label>

                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <select class="form-control job_title" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Add job titles" name="job_title">

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".department_id").change(function() {
        //$(".add_job_title").show();

        var id = $(this).val();
        var selector = $(this).parents('.col-md-6').siblings('.col-sm-6').find('.job_title');

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('project/load_job_title_where'); ?>/" + id,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
                $('.job_title').html("");
                // Use jQuery's each() to iterate over the opts value
                $.each(data, function(index, value) {                       
                    selector.prepend('<option value="' + value.dep_id + '">' + value.job_title + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
});

$(".job_title").select2();

$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 30; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".add_row"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_department_field"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-12"> <div class="col-md-6"> <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Add Department*</label> <div class="col-sm-8 department_input_fields_wrap"> <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;"> <select class="form-control department_id" name="department_id" required> <option value="">--Select department--</option> <?php
                                            foreach($departments as $dep) {
                                                echo '<option value="'.$dep->id.'">'.$dep->department.'</option>';
                                            }
                                        ?> </select> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="col-sm-6 add_job_title"> <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Add Job Title</label> <div class="col-sm-8"> <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;"> <select class="form-control job_title" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Add job titles" name="job_title"> </select> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
});/* Script to add new textboxes for department end*/
```

What this code does is, there is a select element `(department)` through which I can select a department and when I select any one department, the query runs a controller function via ajax and prepends the selected results to another select element `(job title)`. And, when I click on the "add more field" button, it appends another select option row `(department and job title)` where I can make another selection. Everything works fine for the first selection but, when I click the button to display another row, it seems like the `select2()` method is not initialized for that element and also the `job title` select element is not filled with the data. I am not very good at jquery so there might just be some stupid mistake. What would that be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. Call the select2 inside a Dom Ready. Change therefore these lines:

   $(".job_title").select2();

   $(document).ready(function() {

To:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        //
        // first ISSUE: call select2 inside dom ready...
        //
        $(".job_title").select2();
```

2. In the success part of your ajax call you need to call select2 to initialize the newly added select elements or you need to trigger the change event after adding elements.

In the following snippet I used the error aiax call in order to make runnable the snippet itself

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".department_id").change(function() {
        //$(".add_job_title").show();

        var id = $(this).val();
        var selector = $(this).parents('.col-md-6').siblings('.col-sm-6').find('.job_title');


        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('project/load_job_title_where'); ?>/" + id,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
                $('.job_title').html("");
                // Use jQuery's each() to iterate over the opts value
                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    selector.prepend('<option value="' + value.dep_id + '">' + value.job_title + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //
                // for demo purposes
                //
                $('.job_title').empty();
                // Use jQuery's each() to iterate over the opts value
                $.each([{dep_id: 0, job_title: 1010}, {dep_id: 222, job_title: 222}], function(index, value) {
                    selector.prepend('<option value="' + value.dep_id + '">' + value.job_title + '</option>').trigger('change');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {

    //
    // first ISSUE: call select2 inside dom ready...
    //
    $(".job_title").select2();


    var max_fields = 1; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".add_row"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_department_field"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-12"> <div class="col-md-6"> <div class="form-group">  ' +
                    '<label class="control-label col-sm-4">Add Department*</label>  ' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-8 department_input_fields_wrap"> <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">  ' +
                    '<select class="form-control department_id" name="department_id" required> <option value="">--Select department--</option>' +
                '<option value="1">1</option>' +
            '</select> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="col-sm-6 add_job_title">  ' +
            '<div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Add Job Title</label>  ' +
            '<div class="col-sm-8"> <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">  ' +
            '<select class="form-control job_title" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Add job titles" name="job_title"> </select> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div>'); //add input box
            $(wrapper).find('select').select2();
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
});/* Script to add new textboxes for department end*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>



<button type="button" class="btn add_department_field">Add Button</button>
<div class="row add_row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Add Department*</label>

                <div class="col-sm-8 department_input_fields_wrap">
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <select class="form-control department_id" name="department_id" required>
                            <option value="">--Select department--</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 add_job_title">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Add Job Title</label>

                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <select class="form-control job_title" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Add job titles" name="job_title">
                            <option value="11">11</option>
                            <option value="22">22</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to re-initialize the Select2 Function to recognize a new element `job_title` being inserted into Current Loaded DOM

Try this:

```
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-12"> <div class="col-md-6"> <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Add Department*</label> <div class="col-sm-8 department_input_fields_wrap"> <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;"> <select class="form-control department_id" name="department_id" required> <option value="">--Select department--</option> <?php
                                            foreach($departments as $dep) {
                                                echo '<option value="'.$dep->id.'">'.$dep->department.'</option>';
                                            }
                                        ?> </select> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="col-sm-6 add_job_title"> <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Add Job Title</label> <div class="col-sm-8"> <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;"> <select class="form-control job_title" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Add job titles" name="job_title"> </select> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div>'); //add input box
        }
       // Re-Init Select2
       $(".job_title").select2();

    });
```

Comment: Nope. Its still the same.

Comment: @RabinLama can you share a live version of your issue, it will be more helpful to figure out then.